# How to query for status of "Scheduled Jobs" in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I have setup several custom scheduled jobs in my ClearCase Task Scheduler, these jobs are supposed to do automated sync and we usually have no problem with them.

Occasionally the jobs might fail, and I am looking for a CLI way of querying the status of these scheduled jobs and generate a basic report.

Is there such a CLI utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`cleartool schedule`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_schedule.htm)** presented in [Viewing job properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_maint_sched_job_props_view.htm) seems complete enough:

> To view messages and information such as time and status from the last execution of the job, use this command:

```
cleartool schedule –status job-id-or-name
```

> These commands display properties of jobs by using the job-definition syntax documented on the schedule reference page.

Comment: omg, i truly has never used cleartool schedule before for the past 7 years working with CC... Thanks VonC